# MS-Access Oracle Linked-Table Primary Key errors

Tags: database, oracle, ms-access

When linking an Oracle database with MS Access I have been attempting to find out which key is the primary key (PK).

Right-clicking and selecting `Design View` on the linked-table opens up a page explaining the kind of data held within each field e.g., short text, it also includes a `key` symbol next to specific fields and says `Part of the primary key`.

I was suspicious about this because the first table I did it on apparently have a composite primary key made up of 5 columns, two of which could in-fact be empty. I rooted further around the web and found [this Oracle page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1042.htm). It would seem that by looking at the `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` table you can see the actual PK's - and lo-and-behold I seemingly can and there is just one PK in the table given in the previous example.

However, there is seemingly a strange occurrence within this `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` table where for the table in question it lists the PK as a constraint on two columns (NOTE: not a composite key, it says the constraint on column_x is that column_x is a PK and it also states rather randomly that a constraint on column_y is that column_x is a PK).

So, any help on why:

1. MS-Access imports the PK completely incorrectly.
2. Why the `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` table randomly adds in an incorrect constraint on a column?

I am now using the `ALL_CONSTRAINTS` table and it is correct, that is, it only includes the one constraint, i.e., the PK for Table_X is Column_X.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ALL_CONSTRAINTS` doesn't show which columns are part of a primary key constraint.   The `CONSTRAINT_TYPE` column will tell you that a particular constraint is the `P`rimary Key constraint, but you'll need to look at `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` to find out what columns the primary key is composed of.  Also note that you can't necessarily tell if a constraint is the primary key from it's name, since a non primary `U`nique constraint could be named `TABLE_PK` even though it's not the primary key.

It's possible that Access it taking the first Unique constraint it's finding on the linked table and making that the primary key.

Does this query show your your constraint as a single column or composite primary key?

```
select ac.OWNER
     , ac.TABLE_NAME
     , ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME
     , case when max(nvl(position,0)) over (partition by ac.OWNER, ac.TABLE_NAME, ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME) > 1 then 'Composite '
       end ||
       case ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
         when 'P' then 'Primary Key'
         when 'U' then 'Unique'
         when 'R' then 'Foreign Key'
         when 'C' then 'Check'
         else ac.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
       end CONSTRAINT_TYPE
     , acc.COLUMN_NAME
     , acc.POSITION
  from all_constraints ac
  join all_cons_columns acc
    on acc.OWNER = ac.OWNER
   and acc.TABLE_NAME = ac.TABLE_NAME
   and acc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 where ac.owner = user
 order by ac.table_name
     , ac.CONSTRAINT_NAME
     , acc.POSITION;
```

Comment: Checking the `ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` shows  a Composite Primary Key; however, are you suggesting it may not be and it is in fact a single Primary Key yet it is also showing a Unique constraint, which is named `TABLE_PK`?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that a constraint's name is not necessarily indicative of it's function.  I could create a table with a single or multi column primary key named `TABLE_U1` and with a non primary unique constraint named `TABLE_PK`.  What will indicate the constraints function is the `CONSTRAINT_TYPE` column.

Comment: I got ya! Thanks. Rooting further through the database and I'm finding all sorts of oddly named constraints which *suggest* a column is a PK when in actual fact a completely different column is. Bizarrely put together database, but thanks to you I can decipher fact from fiction.